# Azure Cloud Services (extended support) deployment time

Tags: azure, service, cloud

I am trying to deploy Azure Cloud Services. I have been waiting for over 2 hours now with
'Deployment is in progress' apparently doing something.
Is this normal?
I am new to this, should I assume I have made a mistake and cancel? If not, how long can it take please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: After 3 hours the job failed.

Comment: Why are you deploying a Cloud Service?  They are deprecated and will be retired in 2024 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me

Comment: I am trying to deploy Azure Cloud Services (extended support).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in the title.  I haven't worked with extended support but it looks like they wrapped ASM in an ARM deployment.